# how to dynamiclly load controller when using ng-include

Tags: angularjs

My app has a div using ng-include and its src is a variable so it can refer to different pages.Now my problem is that within ng-include,I can't load controller although I managed to load controller's js file successfully.Here is the snippet.

index.jsp

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-include="currentPage"></div>  
//$scope.currentPage="project.jsp"
```

project.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="innerController.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="innerController"></div>
```

The code will cause ng:areq innerController undefined error.

I've loaded innerController.js with my research,and I tried to find possible solutions about the problem.Maybe it's because the angular has bootstraped when controller is loaded.I am really new to angularjs,I can't figure out how to dynamiclly load controller.Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: You can move all functions in `innerController`  to your `myController`.

Comment: @dddd1919  I know I could do like this but there are many controllers like innerController and they have nothing to do with each other.Perhaps it's not a good idea to move them all to myController.

Comment: If so many partial template, why not split them into independent url and use controller and template themself?

Comment: Before you proceed, make sure you first div of currentPage.html contains your innerController declaration. In that fashion, it will work....